# Save data to file and close window on single button click

Tags: javascript, node.js, electron

I've got some data i need to save to a file. On a button click i need to save it and then close the window. However when i call a save() function and a close() function the window will close without having saved anything.

I have tried calling two functions on an event. I have tried creating one function where the data is saved and then window is closed.

```js
const button = document.getElementById('done');
button.addEventListener('click', () => {
  closeWin();
});


function closeWin(){
  saveData();
  const remote = require('electron').remote;
  var window = remote.getCurrentWindow();
  window.close();
}



function saveData(){
  const fs = require('fs');
  fs.writeFile('data.txt', 'Test Data Output', function (err) {
    if (err) throw err;
  });
}
```

Expected: Data saved to file (txt in this case)
Output: Window closed and blank file created with no data

Comment: Saving is (or should be) an aync operation. Can you add your saveData() function too?

Comment: @WillJenkins Added

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the save function you should either return a `promise`, or `callback`, or use `writeFileSync`(not recommended);

Using Promise:

```
function saveData() {
  return new Promise((res, rej) => {
    fs.writeFile('data.txt', 'Test Data Output', function (err) {
      if (err) return rej(err);
      res();
    });
  })
}
```

then close the window, you can use `async-await` here also:

```
function closeWin() {
  saveData()
  .then(()=>{
    const remote = require('electron').remote;
    var win= remote.getCurrentWindow();
    win.close();
  })
}
```

Async-await version:

```
async function closeWin() {
  await saveData();
  const remote = require('electron').remote;
  var win= remote.getCurrentWindow();
  win.close();
}
```

Comment: What is your current `saveData` function? Edit it in the question.

Comment: Just added the full test code i am using atm. I have noticed that it will create the file but not add any data. Before i thought it was doing nothing due to there already being data present.

Comment: You are not using the promise based `saveData`, your saveData **WILL NOT WORK** as it is not returning any promise whatsoever. Please use either `saveData` from my answer and otherwise read about promises it will help you immensely.

Comment: Just got it working. Thanks async worked. And i did but i thought you wanted me to upload the original code. Will mark as answered now. Thanks

Comment: Okay, I got pretty confused too. No problems.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use callback:

```
function saveData(callback) {
// Write code for save your data here
  callback();
}
function closeWin(callback) {
  callback();
 }

closeWin( function() {
 saveData(function() {
   const remote = require('electron').remote;
   var win= remote.getCurrentWindow();
   win.close();
 });

});
```

Comment: The `closeWin(callback)` is unnecessary. and the end block is wrong, you need to pass the function INSIDE `saveData`.